# Dimension of vector of subspace inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $v \in \mathbb R^2, v \ne 0.$ Then the subspace $\{x \in \mathbb R^2, x \cdot v = 0\}$ is of dimension
a) -1
b) 1
c) 2
d) 0.

Note that $\cdot$ denotes the inner product of two vectors in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: So $\bullet$ denotes the inner product. I wonder what $x.v$ means then.

Comment: Do not use pictures for critical sections of your post, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead. Also, what have you tried and what do you think?

Comment: ok i next time i will use mathjax but i m not used to with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $v=(v_1 , v_2$), $v_i \neq 0$

Let $x=(y,z$)

$x.v = y v_1 + z v_2 = 0$

This is one equation in two unknowns. Hope you can take from here

Comment: no i am not able to take from here ,,, but i m thinking that there is one equation and two variable so dimension is one ? am i correct ?

Comment: @niranjanprajapati yes

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- Can a subspace have dimension $-1$?
- If the dimension is $2$, then $v$ is orthogonal to itself.
- If the dimension is $0$, then $v$ has no nonzero orthogonal vector.

Comment: so its answers following form subspace has dimension 1 ??

Comment: If you are able to draw contradictions from the second and third bullet points, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Let $U=\{tv: t \in \mathbb R\}$, then $\{x \in \mathbb R^2: x \cdot v=0\}=U^{\perp}$ and $\mathbb R^2= U \oplus U^{\perp}$.

Can you proceed ?